# How proxy server remember the IP addresses of client to send the response packets back?

Tags: proxy, ip

As I know that NAT tracks the Source IP & port number of the packet before change the IP header to external IP and send to the internet. When receive the response packet, NAT change the packet's header from external IP to private IP by using the value that tracked before.

For proxy server, in 1 second, proxy server retrieves a lot of packets from the clients, proxy server changes the IP header of packet from client's IP to proxy server's IP and send to the internet. When receive response packets, proxy server change IP header from proxy server's IP to client's IP and send back the client.

So, my question is the detail of process how proxy server work? And with the limit of ports(65535), how many connections between proxy server and proxy clients can be established at the same time?

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HTTP proxy or SOCKS proxy simply accepts a TCP connection from the client and maybe after some initial handshake with the client creates a TCP connection to the server. From then on it forwards data (not packets - this is application level!) received on one TCP connection via the other TCP connection as long as both TCP connections are open. There is nothing special about it - it just needs to associate one TCP connection with the other which a simple programming task.

> how many connections between proxy server and proxy clients can be established at the same time?

This is not a security question, but: if the IP address of proxy and client are constant and the proxy is only listening on a single port then of the 4 parts of the connection tuple only the source port on the client can vary. Thus there are in theory at most 65535 connections between client and proxy and in practice even less since the client will not use all ports for connections to the proxy.

Comment: I think I should research more about the "simple programming task", do you have any document about that? Because that is the exactly I want to know. Thanks you so much :D.

Comment: Just wanted to understand the part `not packets - this is application level!`, doesn't the request/response that's flowing b/w the proxy and the backend has a source IP and destination IP? Suppose, that the http proxy is a reverse proxy, then how does the revProxy knows which client to forward the response that it got from the backend server bcz. the response that it would have got from backend would have the destination IP as that of the proxy server itself which is true for all the responses that the proxy receives pertaining to all the requests that it gets from the clients.